# How to ensure feature parity of a product across different platforms

Tags: language-agnostic, multi-platform

this question looks like [How to plan/manage multi-platform (mobile) products](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/176890/how-to-plan-manage-multi-platform-mobile-products) but the answers there suggest using abstractions to ensure a common code repo, which is something that we decided not to do. We a have a mobile website and are in the process of building its native mobile equivalents on Android and iOS.

Each of these projects is being worked on by a different team, and since the development stack is different (to achieve a more native feel) it is really difficult to share code or ui elements: everything on the front end needs to be written from scratch for that particular platform.

All of these projects however need to have the same set of features exposed to their users, and when the product team comes up with a new feature, that feature should be made available on all platforms (unless of course there are some  limitations on a particular platform that make it unfeasible)

The problem we are now facing is this: how do we ensure feature parity, if by accident or miscommunication a feature is planned for one platform only and the other teams have no idea that a new thing has come up and needs to be implemented. Even in these early stages of development, this problem has arisen a number of times, where someone asks "how come X is not available for Y" and the Y team responds "well, because no one told us".

Our first thought was to make the product team more "responsible" but of course relying on humans alone will not get you that far.

We then thought that we could perhaps automate this is in our ticketing system (jira), where the product team could open a ticket and have subtickets automatically created for all platforms, so each team is then notified of the requirement.

Our last thought was that we are probably not the first company ever in the history of coding that has faced this problem, and maybe we should ask for suggestions on how this was tackled by other teams/projects facing the same problem.

So how can we make this process more rigorous (and preferably as much automated as possible) to avoid the "no one told me" situation? How is this normally handled? Are there any best practices?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to solve a people problem with technology.

Comment: Take a pen, a notebook, make a TODO list with two checkboxes, one for Android, one for iOS. Keep an eye on it and talk to your guys sometimes. Problem solved. lol

Comment: You have already done as much as you can to solve the issue: communicate the features through your ticketing system with child tickets. Then insure that everyone knows that a feature started in one area must be completed in all before adding that to the release.